# How can make sections to act like separate web pages and navigate to these in HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```css
#s1{
  background-color:red;
  
height:100px;
}

#s2{
  background-color:blue;
  
height:100px;
}

#s3{
  background-color:orange;
  
height:100px;
}

#s4{
  background-color:yellow;
  
height:100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
 <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- jquery -->
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- icons script -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css">
  
  
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" id="s1">Section1</div>
  
  <div class="row" id="s2">Section2</div>


  <div class="row" id="s3">Section3</div>


  <div class="row" id="s4">Section4</div>

<div>


</body>

</html>
```

How to use css and javascript in these sections to make them act like separate webpages with on scroll function.

Example: During my first scroll, I want to navigate to section 2 with it's separate url.
During my 2nd scroll, I want to navigate to section 3 with it's separate url.
During my 3nd scroll, I want to navigate to section 4 with it's separate url.

Comment: search about one page website and smooth scroll, anchor link, etc etc

Comment: what do you mean by 'separate url?'

like using iframes?
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp

Comment: You'll have to search online for already-written solutions such as [fullPage.js](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage) or write your own -- which is not an easy task.

Comment: @Tibs No, I have seen some tutorials where the url changes from "url to url#sectionid" resulting in navigation of the user from the top of the page to the bottom where that particular section lies.

Comment: I see, anchor link https://www.rapidtables.com/web/html/link/html-anchor-link.html#same-page..
and you should also try the smoothscroll that @TemaniAfif suggested. It will create a smooth scrolling effect on your website. https://github.com/galambalazs/smoothscroll-for-websites.

Comment: What you're looking for is the old style webpage: Frame of navigation, Frame of body, Frame of footer. There was an old HTML tag called the Frameset which was designed for this...

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with the scroll bar. The next best thing is **anchor links**.

When you click these it'll scroll to the specific iframe because we tied them with the iframe IDs:

```
<a href="#F1" title="Click to go to section 1">Section 1</a>

<a href="#F2" title="Click to go to section 2">Section 2</a>

<a href="#F3" title="Click to go to section 3">Section 3</a>

<a href="#F4" title="Click to go to section 4">Section 4</a>
```

And further down your frames...

```
<iframe id="F1" src="URL 1"></iframe>

<iframe id="F2" src="URL 2"></iframe>

<iframe id="F3" src="URL 3"></iframe>

<iframe id="F4" src="URL 4"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recomend you to use scrollify its a fantastic plugin that will save you a lot of time and you will have everything you need. Below is the link
https://projects.lukehaas.me/scrollify/#home

Comment: I saw this, but this becomes laggy after the webpage loads